# "New Game" button deleting Android game progress

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, sharedpreferences

It's been a month since I started learning Java/Android Studio so I apologise beforehand for any silly questions.

I am currently making a simple riddle game with Android Studio - a question is asked, and the right answer gets you to the next activity/question. So, my main menu consists of a Start Interrogation button and a Continue button. Using SharedPreferences I managed to make the game "save progress" so it can get you to the last question you couldn't answer; but my problem comes with the Start Interrogation button. Whenever it is pressed and starts a new game, the continue button will still get you to the last question asked before.

So in simple terms, I want to make the New Game button delete the progress made until then. The only thing that comes to mind is to try and delete the SharedPreferences whenever the button is pressed, but I fail to write such code.

Any tips on what should I do? Help is greatly appreciated. Here's the Java code of my MainMenu.

**MainMenuWithLogo.Java**

```
    public class MainMenuWithLogo extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button mStartInterrogationButton;
private VideoView mLogoprwto;
private Button mContinueButton;
MediaPlayer song;


@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
song.release();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu_with_logo);
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
song = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.chopin);
song.start();
song.setLooping(true);




mLogoprwto = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.logoprwto);
mLogoprwto.setVideoPath("android.resource://its_destination/"+R.raw.teloslogo);
mLogoprwto.start();

mLogoprwto.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

        mLogoprwto.start();
    }
});

mStartInterrogationButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.StartInterrogationButton);
mStartInterrogationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
        startGame();

    }
});

mContinueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ContinueButton);

mContinueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Stage", MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean question00Answered = prefs.getBoolean("QuestionZero", false);
        boolean question01Answered = prefs.getBoolean("QuestionOne", false);
        boolean question02Answered = prefs.getBoolean("QuestionTwo", false);




        if (!(question00Answered)) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuWithLogo.this, QuestionZero.class);

            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
            finish();
        } else if (!(question01Answered)) {



            Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuWithLogo.this, QuestionOne.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
            finish();
        } else if (!(question02Answered)) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuWithLogo.this, QuestionTwo.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
            finish();
        }else {


            Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuWithLogo.this, End.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
            finish();
        }

    }
});

}

private void startGame () {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Intro.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
finish();
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SharedPreferences.Editor.remove()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#remove(java.lang.String)) to delete items saved to SharedPreferences using the item's key. So, when you start a new game, call this to delete the user's progress. Or, if you want to remove **ALL** the stuff in SharedPreferences, call [SharedPreferences.Editor.clear()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#clear()).

Comment: So let's say I want to remove everything from SharedPreferences. As far as my Java file is concerned, i just have to write SharedPreferences.Editor.clear() under mStartInterrogationButton's Public Void onClick? Because that just doesn't work - the word "clear" gets underlined and shows me a message that "non static method "clear"() cannot be referenced from a static context". Same thing happens after I put this new line of code anywhere under onResume...

Comment: @Animated24 Well yeah, Editor is non-static, you get the Editor object by calling `edit()` on the SharedPreferences object. Example: `getSharedPreferences("filename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().clear().apply();`

Comment: Everything's perfect now. I can't thank you enough for this, it's been bugging me for so long!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help. SharedPreferences can be pretty wonky, I've just had a lot of personal experience with them. Essentially, any time you need to edit/delete, you need to do that through the Editor object. If you're only reading objects, you can do that directly from the SharedPreferences object.